# Bounding $\frac{\operatorname{Var}(T)}{\mathbb{E}(T)^{2}}$.

Tags: proof-explanation, asymptotics

I’m reading a text that, for a random variable $T$, looks for the probability $p$ such that the expression $\frac{\operatorname{Var}(T)}{\mathbb{E}(T)^{2}}$ (given below) tends to $0$.

> $\begin{aligned} \frac{\operatorname{Var}(T)}{\mathbb{E}(T)^{2}} &=\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ 3\end{array}\right) p^{3}\left(3(n-3)\left(p^{2}-p^{3}\right)+\left(1-p^{3}\right)\right)}{\left(\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ 3\end{array}\right) p^{3}\right)^{2}} \\ &=\frac{\left(3(n-3)\left(p^{2}-p^{3}\right)+\left(1-p^{3}\right)\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ 3\end{array}\right) p^{3}} \\ & \leq \frac{\left(3 n\left(p^{2}\right)+1\right)}{\frac{(n p)^{3}}{12}} \leq \frac{\left(36(n p)^{2}+12\right)}{(n p)^{3}} \\ &=\frac{36}{n p}+\frac{12}{(n p)^{3}} . \end{aligned}$

When I write out the expression in the second line, it seems like there’s a term $8p^3$ missing from the original text. (There’s also a likely error with the constant $12$, but that doesn’t affect the calculation much). The text concludes that the correct value for $p$ is $p = \omega(1/n)$, but I don’t see how it works with the missing term. I’d like to have some clarification or possible fix.

Comment: what's the distribution of T?

Comment: Also it might be helpful to use: $Var[T]=E[T^2]-E[T]^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no $8p^3$ missing. All that is happening in the second line is that $\binom{n}{3}p^3$ cancels out in the fraction. For the first inequality, the numerator is increased and the denominator is decreased as to increase the overall fraction.

1. $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$: We have $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6}=\frac{n^2}6 - \frac n2+\frac 13= \frac{n^2}{12} + \frac 1{12}(n^2-6n+4)$. For large enough $n$ the second term is positive so that we have $\geq \frac{n^2}{12}$.
2. Since $0\leq p \leq 1$ we have $1-p^3\leq 1$ and $p^2-p^3\leq p^2$ and $3(n-3)\leq 3n$.

Putting this together yields the first inequality.

The second inequality is even lazier: Since $n\geq 1$ we have $36np^2\leq 36n^2p^2$.

Overall, this is the laziest bounding I have seen in a long while.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I ask why the $8p^3$ does not matter, and maybe how I can tell if such terms are not important? Usually my first instinct is to expand the expression and try to work from there, but like this case it doesn’t seem to always work.

Comment: $8p^3$ matters. However, there is no $8p^3$ disappearing as far as I can tell from what you have posted here.

Comment: If we write out the nominator in the second line, shouldn’t we get $3np^2 - 3np^3 - 9p^2 + 8p^3 + 1$?

Comment: Is your issue the first inequality or the first and second line? If it is the first inequality, then you consider the two summands individually like I did above. If you write out the denominator like you do, then you will not easily see the good bounds. You would drop $-3np^3$ and $-9p^2$. However, you wouldn't notice that $-9p^2+8p^3 = -9p^2+9p^3-p^3$ = $-9(p^2-p^3)-p^3$. Since $-p^3\leq 0$ we bound that by $0$. Since $0\leq p\leq 1$ we have $p^2-p^3\geq 0$ and thus $-9(p^2-p^3)\leq 0$. Thus we bound that by $0$ too.